# definition of inverse of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

In this question $\mathbb{C} := \mathbb{R}^2$

the following definition is correct?

---let $(a,b), (c,d) \in \mathbb{C}$, $ (a,b) $ is inverse of $(c,d)$ if

$(a,b) \neq (0,0) $ and $(c,d)=(\left( \frac{a}{(a^2 + b^2)} \right),\left( \frac{(-b)}{(a^2+b^2)} \right))$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Multiply $(a,b)$ by $(c,d)$... what do you get?

Comment: @JpMcCarthy , I edited my question, is correct?

Comment: @JpMcCarthy , sorry .. I have forgot the ","... ;)

Comment: I repeat multiply $(a,b)$ by $(c,d)$... what do you get?

Comment: Questions like this one are odd: what's the problem with multiplying $\,(a,b)\,$ by what you think is its multiplicative inverse and verify you get $\;1\;$ ?

Comment: @JpMcCarthy, $(a,b) \cdot (c,d)=(ac-bd,ad+bc)$..

Comment: @Soviet Now substitute $c$ and $d$.

Comment: @Soviet When $(c,d)$ is your proposed inverse of $(a,b)$... multiply $(a,b)\times \left(\frac{a}{a^2+b^2},\frac{-b}{a^2+b^2}\right)$. A (multiplicative) inverse of an element $x$ (in this context) is an $x^{-1}$ such that $x^{-1}x=1=xx^{-1}$. It can be shown (in this context) that the inverse is unique.

Comment: @Soviet If $(a,b)=(0,0)$ then $(a,b)$ times any complex number is (0,0)... you can't get $(1,0)=1$ if you multiply $(0,0)\times (x,y)$ for any complex number $(x,y)$... i.e. $(a,b)$ does not have a (multiplicative) inverse.

Comment: okok... therefore is correct to use the logical symbol $\wedge$?

Comment: @Soviet It just means 'and'. If I were you I would just replace $\wedge$ with 'and'.

Comment: okok :) thanks soo much!!

Comment: Also note that your question should be about your claim rather than definiton. Definition of multiplicative invers is always the same and abstract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes in this example $\mathbb C$ is identified to $\mathbb R^2$ with the product defined by:

$$(a,b)(c,d)=(ac-bd,ad+bc)$$

We prove easily that $\mathbb R^2$ with the additive law $+$ defined by
$$(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$$
and the multiplicative law as defined above forms a field isomorphic to $\mathbb C$, the zero element is $(0,0)$ and the identity is $(1,0)$.